# Задача по Java Script

Tags: javascript, массивы, count

В программе задан массив array. Напишите функцию `count()`, которая считает количество элементов массива `array` и выводит в консоль сообщение, как в примере.

Пример значений переменных:

```
array = [true, 4, "word", "10n"]
```

Пример результата:

Количество элементов в массиве: 4

Мое решение:  в чем ошибка?

```
let array = [true,4,"word","10n"];
let result = "";
function count(array) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        count +=1;
    }
    console.log(count);
}

count(array)
```

Comment: Тут нет ошибок. Разве что вы не прописали нужный текст

Comment: `function count(array) { return array.length }` ну и в целом тут функция не нужна, можно сразу вывести `console.log(array.length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут нет ошибок. Разве что вы не прописали нужный текст и чуть подрихтовать код

```js
let array = [true, 4, "word", "10n"];

let result = "";

function count(array) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    count += 1;
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(`Количество элементов в массиве: ${count(array)}`)
```

Comment: Не сочтите, что я докапываюсь, но... что автор вопроса, что вы своей правкой не решаете поставленную задачу. Или может я неправильно понимаю сам вопрос? Согласно условия нужна функция — есть. Но использование в ней  .length в корне противоречит сути "подсчёта" количества. Почему бы вам вообще не отказаться от перебора массива и инкремента, а сразу возвращать результат?  —   let count = (array) => array.length; console.log( '=', count(array) );   Функция? Да. Посчитал? Да.)

Comment: Не вижу смысла. Человек учится, вот пусть учится. Видимо изучает циклы.

Comment: Это понятно, что человек учится. Я же не с ним в прения вступил, а спросил ваше мнение. Просто мне стало интересно: действительно ли так проста и нелепа задача, или авторы вкладывали в неё больше смысла?

Comment: Мне в общем-то всё равно кто, что и куда вкладывал.

Comment: Скорее всего надо посчитать количество элементов какого-то определённого типа (судя по разношёрстности массива). Но пока что написано то написано